# How to strip tags string using php with this value format?

Tags: php

How to strip tags string using php with this value format ?

```
<?PHP
$xx = "&lt;p style=&quot;text-align: left;&quot;&gt;test&lt;/p&gt;";
echo strip_tags($xx);
?>
```

When i test this code it's will be echo

```
<p style="text-align: left;">test</p>
```

I want to know how can i strip tags string with this value format ?

Comment: strip_tags and html_entity_decode both can resolve your issue. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strip_tags` and `html_entity_decode` when used together can strip all html tags and special entities like below:

```
<?PHP
$xx = "&lt;p style=&quot;text-align: left;&quot;&gt;test&lt;/p&gt;";
echo $xx = strip_tags(html_entity_decode($xx));
// Output is test
?>
```